# Get separate data from Firebase in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2, firebase, xcode7

I can't get data and write to String variable.

When I do:

```
myRootRef.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: {
            snapshot in
            print(snapshot.value.objectForKey("02-03-2016"))
        })
```

I get all this records (in type - AnyObject):

```
Optional({
    TD =     {
        Entry = 44;
        Name = Tedd;
        Potential = 32;
        StopLoss = 77;
    };
})
```

But I need "Entry", "Name", "Potential", "StopLoss" - put to variables, and after put to textfield...

Help please to understand, how I can do it. 
I can't find solution already more 4 hours....
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to print a value associated with a key. ( a key:value pair)

The key you are specifying is "02-03-2016" and that key doesn't seem to exist.

Assuming your structure is

> ```
>     Entry = 44;
>     Name = Tedd;
>     Potential = 32;
>     StopLoss = 77;
> ```

Then your keys are Entry, Name, Potential and StopLoss

```
print(snapshot.value.objectForKey("Entry")
```

would print

> 44